# How to pass a function to React.Children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a wrapper, which contains a state. I've managed to pass the state `showInfo` to my children, but not the function `setShowInfo` to update it:

```js
const Wrapper = ({ children }: IProps) => {
  const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.map(children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          showInfo,
          setShowInfo,
        })
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is the child component that receive the props:

```js
const ChildComponent = ({ showInfo, setShowInfo }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
     <button onClick={() => setShowInfo(true)}>Click</button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I can console.log `showInfo`, but `setShowInfo` is undefined. How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/1689

Comment: [This artcile](https://medium.com/better-programming/passing-data-to-props-children-in-react-5399baea0356) might be useful.

Comment: No, because I can't simply pass my function as props like this: <ChildComponent setShowInfo={setShowInfo}/>. I must be able to pass a function to any kind of children, hence the abstract Children.map.